# check whether a shape is a group (GroupItems raises an error)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I was trying the following code in Word:

```
Sub MyMacro()

Dim sh1 As Shape

For Each sh1 In ActiveDocument.Shapes
 If sh1.GroupItems.Count > 0 Then
  Debug.Print sh1.Name + " is a group!"
  Else: Debug.Print sh1.Name + " is not a group!"
 End If
Next

End Sub
```

For the actual grouped shape it works, but when the shape is not a group, I get an error:

> Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)': This member can only be
>   accessed for a group

How can I check if the object is a group, besides using `On Error`?

Comment: won't a group actually be of type "group"?  I'd inspect the properties for something to test on.

Comment: yeah, I was looking for something like this but couldn't find anything like "group" in the properties. So far the closest I found is the property `AutoShapeType` that has the value `msoShapeMixed` - not sure if it's a kosher way to check for the group, but maybe I should just use it.

Comment: @SMeaden, maybe you could add it as an answer so I'll accept it? So far I think there's no better solution.

Comment: ok, I have finalised my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I got two very comprehensive answers here, and I'm thankful to their authors. However I would like to avoid `On Error` catching, did not want to rely on shape's name and also did not want to make complicated things like building my own dll. Cindy's solution with `InStr(rng.WordOpenXML, "<wpg:wgp>")` looked like the most closest, but for some reason that piece of code did not work in my document: `<wpg:wgp>` was found for any shape, grouped or not.
Therefore I've decided to post my own solution which is very simple and seems to work correctly for all cases. We just need to use `.AutoShapeType` property (what @SMeaden pointed in the comment):

```
Sub MyMacro()

Dim sh1 As Shape

For Each sh1 In ActiveDocument.Shapes
  If sh1.AutoShapeType = msoShapeMixed Then
  Debug.Print sh1.Name + " is a group!"
  Else: Debug.Print sh1.Name + " is not a group!"
 End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is half true, the "not working" answer is also as half true as this one. I just created another answer to clarify that at least both `Type` and `AutoShapeType` properties should be queried to know if `GroupItems` can be queried.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can go about this in Word. The first two would proabably also work for Excel, but the third is only available in Word.

1. Use the code you have with `On Error Resume Next` and check for `Err.Number`. If it's 0 you have a group, if not then you don't.

   ```
   Sub CheckIfGroup()
       Dim shp As word.Shape
       Dim bIsGroup As Boolean

       Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)

       On Error Resume Next
       Debug.Print shp.GroupItems.Count
       Select Case Err.Number
           Case 0
               bIsGroup = True
           Case -2147024891
               bIsGroup = False
           Case Else
               bIsGroup = False
       End Select
       On Error GoTo 0

       Debug.Print bIsGroup
   End Sub
   ```

   Possibly, there might be other errors, although none occur to me at the moment.
2. Another possibility would be to check the `Name` property, assuming it hasn't been changed by any code. By default, it will be something like "Group 3", so

   ```
   Sub CheckIfGroup()
       Dim shp As word.Shape
       Dim bIsGroup As Boolean

       Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)

       If InStr(shp.NAME, "Group") <> 0 Then
           bIsGroup = True
       Else
           bIsGroup = False
       End If
       Debug.Print bIsGroup
   End Sub
   ```
3. Check the WordOpenXML whether it contains the element tag `<wpg:wgp>` (stands for `wordProcessingGroup`, see the [Open XML SDK documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.office2010.word.drawinggroup.wordprocessinggroup(v=office.15).aspx)). You can't get the WordOpenXML for a Shape, you need to query it for the `Shape.Anchor.Paragraphs(1).Range` - the Range in the Word document with which the Shape is associated.

   ```
   Sub CheckIfGroup()
       Dim shp As word.Shape
       Dim bIsGroup As Boolean
       Dim rng As word.Range

       Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
       Set rng = shp.anchor.Paragraphs(1).Range
       If InStr(rng.WordOpenXML, "<wpg:wgp>") <> 0 Then
           bIsGroup = True
       Else
           bIsGroup = False
       End If

       Debug.Print bIsGroup
   End Sub
   ```

Note that this simple approach can only work if the grouped Shape is the only one anchored to the paragraph. If there are more than one you can still use the WordOpenXML but you'd need to analyze it with XML tools to make sure that the Shape in question is the one that's a Group.

Comment: thank you @Cindy, for different options! I was aware about `On Error` solution, but as I said I was wondering if there was a way to do it differently. Checking the name doesn't seem 100% robust for me - as you indicated, it could have been changed indeed (though for 99% of cases this would work I think).

Answer (score 1):

I came accross the same challenge and found the previous solutions to either be overly complex (error handling) or not working (AutoShapeType). However it shows that by checking the **Shape.Type** property a group will itself identify with the **value of 6** (or as msoGroup).

So the previous code might be adjusted to the following:

```
Sub MyMacro()

    Dim SHP As SHAPE
    
    For Each SHP In ActiveDocument.SHAPES
        If SHP.Type = 6 Then
            Debug.Print SHP.Name & " is a group!"
        Else
            Debug.Print SHP.Name & " is not a group!"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Tested on PowerPoint VBA and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is half true, the "not working" answer is also as half true as this one. I just created another answer to clarify that at least both `Type` and `AutoShapeType` properties should be queried to know if `GroupItems` can be queried.

Answer (score 0):

*Interface Design Error*

IMHO, it looks like an interface design error.  What the designers should have done is also export a `GroupItemsCount` method which client code could inspect before attempting to call `GroupItems`.

*Burying Errors*

I also dislike using `On Error Resume Next` (hereafeter OERN) and on every development team try to persuade colleagues to ship a `DLL` written in .NET (either C# or VB.NET) which buries all these errors thrown by these methods.

*Excel's missing Worksheet Exists method*

So in Excel, we have a Worksheets collection for each workbook but the designers forget to export an Exists method.  One must call `[Worksheets]Item` but if the sheet does not exist then Item throws an error.  Writing one's own [Worksheet]Exists method in a .NET DLL means one can bury the error and avoid VBA OERN.

*SupportsGroupItems*

In your situation, I'd recommend inventing your own `SupportsGroupItems` function which itself has an error handler but it would be hidden from VBA view (so errors get buried).  It would be housed in a .NET DLL.

*Management*

I realise many managers prefer a pure VBA solution and management can be scared of DLL hell but if you them that it is a one-off they should persuadable.  It will only be a very few lines of code.

*Deployment*

Next problem for DLL solution is deployment, not all deployment is done in one complete roll-out and so you'd need to write code to take advantage of the DLL if installed and fallback on VBA if not installed.  You can look in the registry for code to detect the DLL's installation.

*COM Interop Code*

If you have read this far and are convinced that you want your own dll to bury any errors then you need some sample code.  This [blog post](http://csharpforwindesk.blogspot.com/2018/04/c-com-pass-on-excellent-net-image.html) has some sample code.  Key to making a .NET DLL callable from VBA is marking ComVisible(true) in Assembly.cs and ion the build tab of project properties ensure the following checkbox is checked 'Register for COM interop'.

Then ensure a separation of interface and class.  Do you know what? Let me write the code here.  So this is sample C# that **avoids** the Word Primary Interop Assembly by using the `dynamic` keyword.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  // No Word PIA required


namespace SupportsGroupItemsByDynamicLib
{

    public interface ISupportsGroupItemsByDynamic
    {
        bool SupportsGroupItemsByDynamic(object shp);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ISupportsGroupItemsByDynamic))]
    public class CSupportsGroupItemsByDynamic : ISupportsGroupItemsByDynamic
    {
        bool ISupportsGroupItemsByDynamic.SupportsGroupItemsByDynamic(object shp)
        {
            bool bSupportsGroupItems = false;
            try
            {
                dynamic dynaShape = shp;
                dynamic grpShps = dynaShape.GroupItems;
                bSupportsGroupItems = true; // it worked
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // bury the error
            }
            return bSupportsGroupItems;
        }
    }
}
```

So here is some sample VBA code calling the .NET Dll

```
Sub TestByDynamic()
    Dim oGroupItemsByDynamic  As SupportsGroupItemsByDynamic.CSupportsGroupItemsByDynamic
    Set oGroupItemsByDynamic = New SupportsGroupItemsByDynamic.CSupportsGroupItemsByDynamic

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes

        If oGroupItemsByDynamic.SupportsGroupItemsByDynamic(shp) Then
            Debug.Print shp.Name + " is a group! and has " & shp.GroupItems.Count & " items"
        Else
            Debug.Print shp.Name + " is not a group!"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

All the above makes the OERN in VBA look palatable.

Comment: oh wow... I am impressed with so serious approach... to be honest, I really did not want to make my own dll for this task, I meant to manage with just standard simple VBA things. But I'm sure your solution will be helpful for some, thanks for taking time on writing that!

Answer (score 0):

Although they seem contradictory, two answers are both true, so to clarify here are all the situations where the property `GroupItems` of `Shape` is instantiated and can be queried:

- There are the shapes which can be identified by their property `Type` = `msoGroup` (6). Those are the shapes created by grouping 2 or more other shapes.
- There are the shapes which can be identified by their property `AutoShapeType` = `msoShapeMixed` (-2). Those are the shapes corresponding to [SmartArt Graphics](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/learn-more-about-smartart-graphics-6ea4fdb0-aa40-4fa9-9348-662d8af6ca2c).

Note that the question is about Excel and Word, but the answer also applies to PowerPoint.

This answer was made Community wiki so that to fix it if needed or complete it if other possibilities exist.